# how to show my selected pick list value using on click function?

Tags: apex, visualforce, onclick

i have one VF page in that i have one Pick list value while clicking next button it should show my selected pick list value like You have rated location name good/average/low/excellent".

Here is my VF Code:

```
<apex:page Controller="FeedbackController"  showheader="False" sidebar="False">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".bPageBlock").css("background-color","papayawhip");
        $(".bPageBlock").css("border-color","papayawhip");
    });
    </script>
    <style>
   body{ background-color:papayawhip;}
</style>
<apex:form > 
<html>
<head>
<title>Questionnaire3</title>
 <style>
       div.btnGroup{
      text-align: center;margin-top:125px;margin-right:250px;padding:8px*20px;
       }

      div.btnGroup1{
      text-align:right;margin-top:-24px;margin-right:450px;padding:8px*20px;
       }

     div.btnGroup2{
     text-align:left;margin-top:160px;margin-left:125px;padding:8px*20px;font-size:150%
      }

     div.btnGroup3{
     text-align:center;margin-top:100px;margin-right:10px;padding:8px*20px;
     }

     body .bPageBlock .pbHeader {
    background-color: Green; 
}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="btnGroup">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Profilesetting}" value="Profile setting" styleClass="buttonStyle"  style="background:thistle ;width:130px;height:25px;font-size: 14px"/>
    </div>    
<div class="btnGroup1">    
  <apex:commandButton action="{!Logout}" value="Logout" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:thistle ;width:130px;height:25px;font-size: 14px"/>
</div>

       <div class="btnGroup2">  
      <label for="Feed Back">YOUR FEEDBACK <br/><br/><br/></label> 
      <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection > 
     <apex:inputField id="myPicklist" required="true" value="{!Fed.X3_Are_you_satisfied_with_Logistics__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
       </div>

     <div class="btnGroup3">          
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Questionnaire3}" value="Next page" onclick="if(true){alert('You Have selected'+result);   }" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:lightcoral ;width:120px;height:25px;font-size: 13px"/>    
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

But My on click function is not working here how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="showPciklistval()">Click me</button> 

function showPciklistval(){
    var myPicklistVal = document.getElementById(myPicklist).value; //id of the apex:inputfield picklist field
    alert('myPicklistVal==='+myPicklistVal);
    myActionfuncton();

}

<apex:actionFunction name="myActionfuncton" action="{!Questionnaire3}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Anujit, Its not  Working for me...

Comment: This JS function wont work because there is an action attribute in the command button which calls the  apex method and refreshes the page. Please use a html button and call a js function onclick of the button. this js function will inturn will call your apex method Questionnaire3

Comment: Do like this:
<button onclick="showPciklistval()">Click me</button> 

function showPciklistval(){
    var myPicklistVal = document.getElementById(myPicklist).value; //id of the apex:inputfield picklist field
    alert('myPicklistVal==='+myPicklistVal);
 myActionfuncton();

}

<apex:actionFunction name="myActionfuncton" action="{!Questionnaire3}"/>

Comment: Its Not working Anujit...

Comment: Please paste your code here. So that I can check

Comment: <button onclick="showPciklistval()">Nexpage</button> <apex:actionFunction name="myActionfuncton" action="{!Questionnaire3}"/>

Comment: did u put the actionfunction in apex:form? and u have to write the JS function which i have mentioned above